# Looking for a Fiction Book where One Vote Decides the Result of the Election

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the title and author of a book.

I believe the action takes place in XXth century's USA, in an alternative history.
Statistical and political analyses made huge progresses, to the point that they can forecast with a 100% accuracy the result of upcoming elections.
A president is about to be elected, and their analysis show that the result of the election will actually be decided by a single man.
They start looking for this man, to ask him to vote, and, actually, to decide who will be the next president.

Does that ring a bell?
I'm sorry if the plot I described is vague, I never read that book, just remember hearing someone mention it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like [*Franchise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_%28short_story%29), a 1955 short story by Isaac Asimov. In *Franchise*, Asimov's grand computer, Multivac, selects a single person to answer a series of questions which determines the result of the election.
Also see [this similar post on the Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14333/47234), which includes a fuller description and a link to the story in the comments.